# Unable to use Custom Action DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, windows-installer, setup-project, custom-action

I am trying to use install custom action dll in a setup project I created in Visual Studio 2008 and x86 platform. I created the project using instruction given on following website: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335516/Custom-Action-in-Visual-Studio-setup-projects
I am getting an error as "Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor." This error I found in a log file created during installation. I searched online for this error but it was not helpful. Also, my dll and setup project are getting compiled successfully. But I am having a warning as "Entry point 'Install' not found in module for 'C:\Users...\Release\deinstallCustAct.dll' custom action 'deinstallCustAct.dll' " and after compilation the dll file which I have added to Install folder of Custom Action is underlined by red curvy line. I am using custom actions for the first time. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I was not passing the MSIhandle to the custom action function. That's why it was giving me that error and warning. I passed "MSIHANDLE hInstall" to my custom action dll function to get rid of that error and warning! Thank you everyone for your consideration!

Answer (score 0):

I used VSInstaller first time and I face the same problem in the same tutorial

For **me helped** to build project in **Release** mode and check that all dependent librares exists. For me it is [VCRUNTIME140.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0pHg.png) (here picture from CFF Explorer)

This error happens because I built project in VS2019 in **Debug** mode and compilled  DLL used for their work vcruntime140**D**.dll, so this DLL was not found on machine without VS and therefore installer was crashed!